# Set Elements value to its ID

Tags: jquery, input, element

I need to set the value of all input elements to their id with jquery. I tried the following which does not work.

```
<HTML>
<input id="fname" name="fname" type="text">

<script>
$('input').val($('input').attr('id'));
```

Comment: You'll have to loop through individual elements, `val` as a setter sets the same value for all the elements in the jQuery wrapped set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should `iterate` through that element collection, and in each iteration you have to set the current element's `id/value` by its own `value/id`. You have to read [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) and [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to get more knowledge about it.

Try,

```
$('input').each(function(){   
 $(this).attr('id',$(this).val());
});
```

or if i misunderstood your title,

Try

```
$('input').each(function(){   
 $(this).val($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

---

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/bf4jx/1/)

Comment: the OP has asked to set value of input to their corresponding id. Instead, your code does the opposite.

Comment: @Stoic Sorry misunderstood the question. Corrected accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

***[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bf4jx/)***

You have to use `.each()` to loop through all input elements and set its value using `this.id`.

```
$('input').each(function(){
    $(this).val(this.id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate through each input element and set their value accordingly. Moreover, I would advise to do this once, when the page has been loaded.

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input').each(function() {
    $(this).val($(this).attr('id'));
  });
});
```